# Adding new query parameter to hyperlinks dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several hyperlinks in my homepage. I would like to add a query parameter at the end of each hyperlink dynamically.

For example;

```
<a href="detail.aspx?id=2" target="_blank" >xyz</a>
<a href="detail.aspx?cid=5" target="_blank" >pqr</a>
```

will be converted to

```
<a href="detail.aspx?id=2&redirectFrom=hp" target="_blank" >xyz</a>
<a href="detail.aspx?cid=5&redirectFrom=hp" target="_blank" >pqr</a>
```

a new query parameter "**redirectFrom**" with value have been added to the converted hyperlinks.

How I can achieve it using ASP.net C#?

Comment: You can [also] do that in javascript/jquery

Comment: @AlexR.Yes I can do that easily in javascript but I would like to do it on server side.

Comment: Is `redirectFrom=hp` going to be the same for all links or `hp` value is going to change? The issue is if you do it server side, you will have to actually *reload* the page to be able to change the Request URL.

Comment: @AlexR.same for all without reload.

Comment: @Hoque- If it's going to be the same for all, what do you need it for then? Can you please explain more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexR.I have a site which has been built a year before and the site contains several links which are obtained from the database and now for a reason I need to add a query parameter to indicate that the link has been clicked from the home page of the site. It might be done in other way.But I thought adding a parameter in the link might be a good attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath` instead of dynamically modifying each Link in your page. Please make sure whether or not `UrlReferrer` is null or not with every Request.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.